# Insert row automatically if no data entered in last 24 hours

Tags: mysql

I have a table called imports. These are typically being made daily, but I want to be able to record when a day goes by and an import isn't made. Currently, I'm doing this through just running a PHP script that checks the last entry vs the current entry and inserts rows with a null value in created for any missing days. I was hoping there would be a way to schedule something like this directly within the database.

**imports**

```
import_id      |  created             | success | error
    0001       | 2015-01-21 10:39:53  |    4    |   3
    0002       | 2015-01-22 10:39:53  |    1    |   0
    0003       | 2015-01-23 10:39:53  |    1    |   1
```

If 24 hours pass and no import is made :

**new imports**

```
import_id      |  created             | success | error
    0001       | 2015-01-21 10:39:53  |    4    |   3
    0002       | 2015-01-22 10:39:53  |    1    |   0
    0003       | 2015-01-23 10:39:53  |    1    |   1
    0003       | null                 |   null  |   null
```

Comment: Use the MySQL Event Scheduler.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at this as an option but was having some difficulty understanding how to implement it here. 

http://www.9lessons.info/2012/10/mysql-event-scheduler.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html

Was looking at the above articles and can't seem to find out how to check if a row was inserted that day. Could you point me to the documentation or give me a small sample query? Appreciate any help.

Comment: If you're having trouble getting it to work, post what you tried and we'll help you fix it. But basically you just write the query that you want to run, and put it in `CREATE EVENT` to tell it how often to perform the query.

Comment: Is your problem with the event scheduler, or writing a query that adds the row if there hasn't been any activity in the past day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a query that adds the row you want, and then schedule it using `CREATE EVENT`:

```
CREATE EVENT AddRow
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
DO
    INSERT INTO imports (import_id, created, success, error)
    SELECT MAX(import_id), null, null, null
    FROM imports
    HAVING MAX(created) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks, issue was making the query if there wasn't any activity. Figured it out, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.